# Two const variables with same name in 2 independent .cpp file will lead to a link error?

Tags: c++, compilation, linker, constants

Thanks for reading my question.

I understand that by default const objects are local to a file and the key word extern would be the best practice to share a variable across different files.

Chatgpt told me that I could reproduce a link error where there were 2 variables with same name in 2 .cpp file withine same project.

```
a.cpp b.cpp
```

In a.cpp:

```
const int myConstVar = 42; // Definition in a.cpp

int main() {
    return myConstVar;
}
```

In b.cpp

```
// b.cpp
const int myConstVar = 10; // Another definition in b.cpp

int someFunction() {
    return myConstVar;
}
```

Then I build the solution in VS2022 however nothing happened.

Here are my questions:

1. Though 2 cpp files are independent from each other, given they are in the same project, IDE should compile them seperatedly and automatically do the link job. Do I have any misunderstanding here?
2. Is there any way/logs/outputs to let me make sure the link really happens?
3. Why there was no link error like "multiple definition"?

Thanks for your help in advance

Comment: _Chatgpt told me that I could reproduce a link error_. ChatGPT is wrong (again). More generally, ChatGPT doesn't know how to program in C++, it is just a generator that pastes plenty of C++ snippets together without understanding them,

Comment: if declare `myConstVar` in a  common header and include that header in both `a.cpp, b.cpp` and link them, you should get the link error

Comment: Global `const` variables are implicitly `static`, having internal linkage. Which means the name is not visible outside of the translation unit; it's not exposed to the linker. There shouldn't be any linker errors in the example shown. If you drop `const` from both definitions, you may be able to observe a linker error. You may additionally need to call `someFunction` from `main`, or otherwise refer to something in `b.cpp` from `a.cpp`; the linker may discard an object file that appears unused.